# Fatal error when using scripts through virtualenv - extra quotes around python.exe

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv

I am very new to Python and recently installed Python 2.7.6 x86 on Windows.  I am trying to create an environment via virtualenv.  I installed Python, then installed pip and virtualenv globally.  I then CD'd to the directory I wanted to create an environment in and ran `virtualenv env`.  Then I activated it with `env\scripts\activate`.  Now, when I try to run any of the scripts through virtualenv (pip, easy_install, etc.) I get the following error:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using
'""[dir]\env\Scripts\python.exe"" "[dir]\env\Scripts\pip.exe" --version'
```

Note the extra quotes around the python exe.  It has two sets of quotation marks, not just one set.

I have a feeling that this is a path error.  The path is getting set in activate.bat, but looks correct there - `set "VIRTUAL_ENV=[dir]\env"`

Let me reiterate that scripts work fine globally.  I am only seeing this error in virtualenv.

Where is that extra set of quotation marks coming from?  How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this problem, because i put my virtual env directory in a directory with .(dot) and spaces in name. When i renamed the parent dir, it worked.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the new answer to this question after all this time because I recently installed Python on a new machine and ran into this issue again, and when I checked my virtualenv path, it did indeed have spaces in it.  When I removed the spaces from the path name, I no longer had the issue.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I had the same issue, but mine was because I had a dash (-) in the directory name... *sigh*

Answer (score 28):

Same error for me here. Until I tried the following (being inside of my venv) and it worked:

```
(venv) > python -m pip
```

or

```
(venv) > python -m easy_install
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get over this error by creating my directory which will have virtual environment under C:\Python27 and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall python inside a folder without spaces and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem with respect to pip and had to upgrade my python installation to 2.7.6 and reinstall pip.

Comment: Were you not using 2.7.6 when this happened to you?  I am using 2.7.6, and I can't upgrade any further because the libraries I want to use in the future aren't available for 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is also present in virtualenvwrapper-win.

[The system cannot find the path specified](https://github.com/davidmarble/virtualenvwrapper-win/issues/38)

Here's how they resolved it

"I changed WORKON_HOME to C:\PythonEnvs and it now works."

So, the advice on windows continues to be: no spaces in path names.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the same error using following command inside venv.

```
python -m easy_install pip
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after installing both python versions 2.7 and 3.4, fixed after upgrading `virtualenv` on python 3.4 version with command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade virtualenv
```